# iOS Appium on Raspberry-Pi using Quamotion

Tags: ios, automation, raspberry-pi, automated-tests, appium

I tried setup Appium (iOS) on a Raspberry-Pi 4 using the tutorial on http://docs.quamotion.mobi/docs/xcuitrunner/tutorials/appium-on-raspberrypi/ .

How do I retrieve the machineId which is needed to request a trial license?

Comment: How did you bypass the ansible error regarding arm architecture?

Comment: I did not observe any. Could you post the ansible error?

Comment: you install ansible on a control machine (not on RPi). Ansible script installs appium + middleware on RPi. 
This worked seamlessly for me. I did setup about 10 RPi devices (each with 2 connected iPhones) in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did run the playbook first with a dummy license. This installed already all components on the RPi.

Running `/usr/share/xcuitrunner/xcuitrunner` displayed the machineId.

You can run the playbook once more to update the license file.

Comment: Thanks. I am now able to automate my iOS devices from a Raspberry-Pi  using Appium.